# How to enable harmony syntax support in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, yield, ecmascript-harmony

I used node.js(0.11.13) with `--harmony` flag and used `function *()` and `yield` keywords.

I tried to simplify my development on node.js with help of coffeescript, so far it works great but I went into troubles with `yield` and declaring a generator - it complains about *'reserved keyword yield'*.

Any ideas?

Comment: After 4 hours of research I found that original coffeescript have stucked for years at adding yield support... I see only some blackmagic ways like putting the whole function body in pure js with ``, or using https://github.com/paiq/blackcoffee... so sad :( and hax yield support with superior power of macros...

Comment: And I really frightened to use this in production... It feels like blackmagic being ruled by another even more powerful blackmagic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to open the gate to the black dimension is:

```
co = require 'co'
sleep = require 'co-sleep'

co(`function*(){1`
    console.log 'hi!'
    `yield sleep(1000)`
    console.log 'bye!'
`1}`)()
```

It's seems to be perfectly valid coffee-script, though, webstorm cofeescript plugin cries about errors, but it works.

Also the following solution(vanilla coffeescript and gulp) is possible:

```
co      = require 'co'
sleep   = require 'co-sleep'
$       = (cor) -> cor
$yield  = (cor) -> cor

do co $ ->
    console.log "hi!"
    $yield sleep(1000)
    console.log "bye!"

gulp.task 'node-js', ->
    gulp.src config.srcServerJs, {base: config.srcServerJsBase}
    .pipe plumb()
    .pipe coffee()
    .pipe replace(/\$\(function\(/g, '\$(function*(')
    .pipe replace(/\$yield\(/g, 'yield (')
    .pipe gulp.dest(config.dstServerJs)
```

magic: no errors in IDE :)

**Update**
After trying and reading a lot of stuff about coffee, ecma6 and its future I decided to give up on coffeescript and go with ECMA6 with support of traceur for both node.js and client-side

Comment: Any idea how to fix source map of modified js?

Answer (score 4):

It's actually now possible to use `yield` in coffeescript 1.9.x

from [coffeescript's website](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow)

> CoffeeScript functions also support ES6 generator functions through the yield keyword. There's no `function*(){}` nonsense — a generator in CoffeeScript is simply a function that yields.

example:

```
perfectSquares = ->
  num = 0
  loop
    num += 1
    yield num * num
  return
```

Answer (score 3):

Use (for example) my fork: https://github.com/xixixao/coffee-script

There are other ones with different syntax.

Comment: This does not solve the problem with broken highlighting in webstorm. And I do not understand how to use forks via npm

Comment: Generators are supported by master. To use forks/master branch via npm use `npm install jashkenas/coffee-script` (the instructions are in the README of my fork as well, but that one is now obsolete).

Answer (score 1):

Generators support (the yield keyword) landed in the master branch some time ago, but haven't been released yet.

You can get it via NPM and put as a dependency in package.json:

```
npm i jashkenas/coffeescript
```