# Iterate over ES6 Set/Map in Coffeescript (with `of` operator)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ecmascript-6

How can one iterate over an ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in Coffeescript?

In Javascript one would use e.g.

```
s = new Set()
s.add({a: 1})
for (x of s) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

However Coffeescript has its own `of` operator that gets converted to `in`, i.e.:

```
console.log(x) for x of s
```

becomes `... for (x in s) { ... }`.

How can one access Javascript's `of` operator in Coffeescript?

One could write their own custom iterator by cycling over `s.values().next()`, but that'd be an abomination. :)

Comment: i don't think you can really. you can use a higher-order function, which without the parens to invoke is nearly as clean as native syntax.

Comment: @dandavis: You mean e.g. `s.forEach (x) -> console.log(x)`?

Comment: yeah, something like that, you might need your own function to handle Object/Set inputs...

Comment: related: [How to enable harmony syntax support in coffeescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24700210/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Coffeescript 2.0](http://coffeescript.org/announcing-coffeescript-2/) — `for …from`

> JavaScript’s for…of is now available as CoffeeScript’s `for …from` (we already had a `for …of`): `for n from generatorFunction()`

### Coffeescript 1.0 — Backticks

One option is to use the backtick to embed raw Javascript i.e. http://coffeescript.org/#embedded.

```
`for (x of y) { }`
```

Answer (score 9):

There's currently no way to use the new Javascript ES6 `of` operator from coffeescript (as of 1.9.2). The best option for now is to use `s.forEach (x) -> ...` or `m.forEach (value, key) ->` as mentioned above.

For a set:

```
s = new Set
s.add {a: 1}

s.forEach (v) =>
  console.log v
```

For a map:

```
m = new Map
m.set {a: 1}, {b: 2}

m.forEach (v, k) =>
  console.log k, v
```

If you want to avoid creating new functions for whatever reason, you can use iterators directly from coffeescript. But its a little bit nasty. For sets:

```
i = s.values()
while(v = i.next(); !v.done)
  console.log v.value
```

For a map:

```
i = m.entries()
while(v = i.next(); !v.done)
  [key, value] = v.value
  console.log key, value
```

The parentheses on the while loop are necessary to make the while loop dependant on v.done.

They can be done on one line too - but it looks pretty bad:

```
i = s.values(); console.log v.value while(v = i.next(); !v.done)
```

Comment: In the first line, did you mean to say "the new JavaScript ES6 **`of`** operator"?

Comment: Notice that `of` uses iterators in a little different way. It has an implicit `try finally` wrapped around that calls `i.return()` should the loop body return prematurely.

Comment: Yeah - fixed the reference to the `of` operator (thanks!). And fascinating, @Bergi

Comment: This is no longer correct.  Could you please edit to add a note re. Coffeescript 2.0? http://coffeescript.org/announcing-coffeescript-2/

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something like this:

```
eat food for food in ['toast', 'cheese', 'wine']
```

(where `eat` is a function)

In your case, you would do:

```
console.log(x) for x in s
```

Ref: http://coffeescript.org/#loops

It's helpful to use the coffeescript REPL. You can open it by typing `coffee` in your console. Try the following code:

```
_ = require 'underscore' #substitute underscore for lodash, if you prefer
s = ["a", "b", "c"]
console.log(x) for x in s
```

Edit:

Unfortunately, the Set functionality from ES6 doesn't seem to have made it into Coffeescript yet. Consider using underscore the lodash methods `_.unique()` or `_.union()` to mimic the functionality you're looking for.

For the example above:

```
s = _.unique ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c"]
console.log(x) for x in s
```

Comment: I think you have misread the question. What needs to work, using your example, would be `eat food for food in new Set(['toast', 'cheese', 'wine'])`, which fails because CoffeeScript converts that to a `for` loop. ES6 Sets have neither a `length` property nor indexes.

Comment: I did in fact misread it. Thanks for the clarification. It doesn't look like sets have made it into Coffeescript yet. You may be able to use underscore or lodash to get around this, though. See my edit, above

Comment: Thanks @Ashwin -- another option is in the comments to the question (`s.forEach (x) -> ...`). I will post if I see anything that illuminates further.

Comment: No problem at all. `s.forEach()` works well if you're working with pure JS, but the `s = new Set()` line will throw a ReferenceError in Coffeescript.